# UIWebView unsupported in ASP.NET CKEditor

Tags: uiwebview, ckeditor, ckeditor.net

I'm developing a locked down tablet app for students meant to bring up a testing website. Currently the site uses the asp.net version of the CKEditor control with no problems in Safari.

However, when I try to use the editor with the UIWebView control (because of the iOS versions we are committed to supporting, I cannot try other controls like WKWebView) I run into two issues:

1. The cursor seems to run away from the text (from what I can tell this spacing seems to have to do with spaces specifically although given how slowly it moves away from where new text is entered, it's hard to tell).
2. When the cursor reaches the bottom of the text box it will simply move below it, rather than adding scrollbars.

Is this simply a matter of the lag between the development of the base CKEditor control and its conversion to ASP.NET or is this a fundamentally broken part of the control?